# Is ‘five for ten’ the same as ‘five out of ten’?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I’ve heard the phrase 5 *for* 10 several times in a tv show in contexts where I would have used 5 *out of* 10 (of course different numbers work as well).
I searched for it but found not a single page mentioning such a usage of the word “for”.
So my question is, is that a common used expression and if so, does it have the exact same meaning as 5 out of 10?

Comment: Could you give us some examples of the contexts?

Comment: If you get 10 questions and get 5 of them right, you say “5 *out of* / *for* 10”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of the word **for** here is usually in a sport or competition context. It refers there to the number of successes, out of a certain number of attempts:

> The batter was 2 **for** 4 in the game.

*(Above quote from Dictionary.com)*

I can't think of any other contexts that I would hear it used, unless somebody was using it colloquially as though something were a sport:

> John's been trying to chat up women all night. He's currently **zero for five**.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for.